# Hide command prompt in laravel desktop application

Tags: php, laravel, desktop-application, serve, phpdesktop

I have developed a laravel desktop application and it is working fine. When i run my laravel desktop application php artisan serve command automatically starts in the command prompt and it shows on the desktop like this
[image]
but I do not require to be shown it should run in the background. guide me for this thank you in advance

Comment: You may run without the `artisan` command like `localhost/projectname`

Comment: I do not running it with artisan serve setup automatically start php artisan serve but if i close the command prompt it shut down the desktop application

Comment: Artisan serve is used as a development environment. It's not intended to use as "production" env. If you want to run the application locally, maybe you should take a look at virtual machines, or services that will start automatically (like Valet). Maybe a docker container is a good solution?

Comment: Artisan commands are running automatically i don't have any issue for this but i want these commands should run in the background and should not appear on the window as you can see in the above image command prompts are shown on the application

Answer (score 0):

Hi thanks for everyone who tried their best to help me out i got my solution you just need to change your setting.json file for desktop application and shut down the console as default

```
"debugging": {
    "show_console": false,
    "subprocess_show_console": false,
    "log_level": "DEBUG4",
    "log_file": "debug.log"
},
```